# Mark Two Points Which Have a Distance of $\sqrt{3.6}$

Tags: geometry, construction

Here is a grid graph with $7$ horizontal and $7$ vertical lines which are $1$ unit apart. It is trivial to mark two points which have a distance of $\sqrt{36}$.

Drawing **at most two extra lines** as helpers, could you mark two points which have a distance of $\sqrt{3.6}$?

[image]

Comment: By points, do you mean the intersection of these lines? Or anywhere on the lines?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac arbitrary point can be made only if that helps.. but the exact position can't be explicitly specified unless it's in an intersection.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course we need to use Pythagoras.

> So we need to write $3.6=\frac{18}{5}$ as the sum of two squares.
>  $\frac{18}{5} = \frac{90}{25}= \frac{81+9}{25}= (\frac{9}{5})^2+(\frac{3}{5})^2$

This leads to the following solution:

> [image]

Here is another more compact solution.

> [image]
>  The two lines have the equations
>  $$y=4-2x\\2y=x-1$$
>  Their intersection point is $(\frac{9}{5},\frac{2}{5})$.
>  From there to point $(0,1)$ we have $\Delta x=\frac{9}{5}$ and $\Delta y=\frac{3}{5}$ giving the same distance as the first solution.

Comment: So fast, yep this is correct, well done! If you want more challenge, could you solve it in a grid graph of only $4$ horizontal and $4$ vertical lines? :)

Comment: @athin Ébe Isaac's solution would fit.

Comment: Unfortunately, their solution uses $5$ horizontal lines, so the challenge is still running :)

Comment: @athin number of lines used is not part of the question. Could you please add to it if you would like it to be accomplished with minimum use of horizontal lines? (Also, my solution can be obviously altered to use 4 horizontal lines ;))

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Oh this is just a fun challenge, in the end I'll give the checkmark to this answer actually (as the first and the calculated one imo) ^^

Comment: @athin I have now added a solution to your bonus challenge.

Comment: @athin, modified my solution to work even for 2x2 grid.

Comment: But Ebe's solution doesn't actually produce a distance of sqrt(3.6).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Great job, checkmark is given! :D

Answer (score 0):

A viable solution:

> [image]

Explanation:

> The dotted circle has a radius of $\sqrt{3.6}$ hence distance between any point on the circle and its centre is $\sqrt{3.6}$. The two blue lines are drawn so as to intersect on a point on the circle so that the red line from the centre can connect the intersection. The length of the red line is indeed $\sqrt{3.6}$. There should be possibly many solutions to this problem.
>  **Note**: one of the blue lines are overlapped by the red line

Proof:

> With the centre of the circle as the origin, the two lines can be written as
>  $y= \frac{1}{2}x + 2$ and $y = x$
>  They [intersect at $(\frac{4}{3}, \frac{4}{3})$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D-0.5x+%2B+2%2C+x%3Dy)
>  Distance from the the origin to the intersection point is
>  $\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}^2 + \frac{4}{3}^2}$
>  $= \sqrt{\frac{32}{9}}$
>  $\approx \sqrt{3.6}$

Comment: Well, how to get the circle in the first hand?

Comment: Sorry, @athin, I took advantage of a computer as there is no [tag:no-computer] tag for this puzzle :)

Comment: @athin Ignore the circle. The intersection of those two blue lines defines a point that is the required distance from a gridpoint.

Comment: $\frac{32}{9}=3.5555$ so it is only very approximately $3.6$.

Comment: I agree, @JaapScherphuis, nonetheless it's a close approximation when considering the value of its square root.